# Laravel - Passing id from one page and reference that id for the next page's table data

Tags: php, laravel, reference, laravel-blade

Good day. I'm having a hard time solving how to pass an id from a table (Region table) and use that id as a reference (idParent) for the table (Province table) on the next page. For context, all regions has an id, and the provinces has an idParent which is an id from regions.

I think I'm missing something in my routing, that's why I can't pass the data. Below are snippets of my blade file, Controller, and web.php. Thank you for helping.

web.php

```
// Masterlist Province
Route::get('province/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\FormControllerMasterlistProvince::class, 'viewRecord'])->middleware('auth')->name('province');
Route::post('province.editprovince', [App\Http\Controllers\FormControllerMasterlistProvince::class, 'editprovince'])->name('province.editprovince'); 
Route::post('province.deleteprovince', [App\Http\Controllers\FormControllerMasterlistProvince::class, 'deleteprovince'])->name('province.deleteprovince');
```

FormControllerMasterlistProvince.php

```
// view record
public function viewRecord($id)
{
    $data = DB::table('province')->where('idRegion', '=', $id)->get();
    return view('province',compact('data'));
}
```

region.blade.php

```
@foreach ($data as $key => $item)
<tr>
<td class="text-center">
    <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle me-1" type="button"
                id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                ACTION
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a href="{{ route('province') }}">
                ㅤProvinceㅤ</a> 
                
                <a href="/province/{{ $item->id }}">
                ㅤProvince (Test Button)ㅤ</a> 

                <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editregion" 
                data-myid="{{$item->id}}" 
                data-mytitle="{{$item->region}}">
                Updateㅤ</span>
                </a> 

                <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteregion" 
                data-myid="{{$item->id}}" 
                data-mytitle="{{$item->region}}">
                Delete</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Should I be passing the id from the region controller to the province controller and also reference the id in the routing? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Yes, you'd need a route parameter or a URL parameter to know which region/province to show. Btw, you have two duplicate route definitions (`Route::get('region'...` and `Route::get('province'...` - one of the duplicates will not work)

Comment: how can i show that parameter? and thanks for pointing out the duplicate, i already removed it :)

Comment: There's documentation on [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters) and [Generating URLs To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes) with parameters. The example should give you a hint on how to use them.

Comment: It's giving me an error saying, "Missing required parameter for [Route: province] [URI: province/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]."

I've restructured my code above, can you help me what I did wrong?

Comment: In my region blade file, i have a main button which should redirect the id of the table row to the routing and i also have a test button where it passes the id. The test button shows the id in the url when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

public function viewRecord($id)
{

```
$data = DB::table('province')->where('idRegion', '=', $id)
  ->pluck('id')->toArray();
//gets the value of the array key
$gets_value = end($data);
return view('province',compact('gets_value'));
```

}

Comment: change your viewRecord function to this then compact $gets_value ensure you save your records before compacting

Comment: Please [edit] to add the comment with the explanation to the currently code-only answer. Use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for making pretty.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).